# Mixed Spin-Glass/Ferromagnetic phase in Sherrington-Kirkpatrick (SK) model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, spin-models, ferromagnetism, disorder

I'm studying the Sherrington-Kirkpatrick model in the book of Nishimori *Statistical Physics of Spin Glasses and Information Processing*, in particular the SK model and its phase diagram. I report here the specific page:

[image]

He says that there is a line which separates the spin-glass (SG) and ferromagnetic (F) phases, as predicted by the replica symmetric *ansatz*. Even if this line is incorrect (since the full replica symmetry breaking *ansatz* is the correct one), it can be computed numerically by the saddle point equations for $m$ and $q$. How can one plot that line? This is a sort of temperature as a function of the mean value of the couplings $J_0$, but what are the conditions to plot this function?

Comment: Can you please clarify what $J$ and $J_0$ denote?